# providing default tone for alarm application

Tags: java, netbeans, alarm

[image: the structre of the project]

I am coding an alarm app in Java in Netbeans. I want to provide default tone with the alarm. I created a folder named rsrc and saved the tone in that folder. I included this code to get the tone

```
URL turl = this.getClass().getResource("rsrc/bb.mp3");
String s1=turl.getFile();
```

While this worked in Netbeans it didn't worked in the jar file that netbeans created in the dist folder. 
 Can someone please help me how to get it work with jar file or a way to distribute my application with the default tone include

Comment: Can you provide structure of your project? i.e. tree hierarchy of folder

Comment: @SachinPasalkar Thank you for your response.I added a picture to show the structure of the project

Answer (score 1):

Paths are relative to your current directory.  When you run the program, this won't work.  You need to have or find an absolute install directory and prefix your path with that.

Comment: But this is not an setup file. I'm just want to use it as a jar file.

Answer (score 1):

Try this one:

```
URL turl = this.getClass().getResource("./alarm/rsrc/bb.mp3");
 String s1=new File(turl.getFile()).getAbsolutePath();
```

Comment: Have you tried using jar? Can you also show the jar folder structure then?

Comment: I tried using jar. I got this error while building                    Not copying library C:\Users\vinnu\Dropbox\projects\alarm\${libs.JLibrary.classpath} , it can't be read.

Comment: Find updated code.This must work with your application and in jar also

Comment: Clean and compile the code then create the jar. Above change will not going to affect jar creation there must be other problem

Comment: I have created same structure(In Eclipse) like your project but in my case it works fine :(. Give me the path of file from bin folder. If you don't know share complete navigator screen shot.(i.e. Same screen that you share but it should be full)